# objectobject returning with async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Guys i have this problem with my code

` 
get data

```
<script>
  let dataBtn;
  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch("./prodotti.json");
    return await response.json();
     
  }
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  const btn = document.querySelector("#get");
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const data = await fetchData();
     //console.log(data);
    container.appendChild(newDiv).innerHTML = data.name;
  });
</script>
```

`

when i click on the button appears [object object] instead of the json data

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a brief sample of the JSON data you are trying to retrieve. The data you're getting is an array with 2 objects inside. the data you want is probably located inside of the objects. With more info on the data, I can help you more to retrieve exactly the data you want

Comment: `response.json();` may be misleadingly named. It says, JSON parse the fetched data and return the object, which then logs (properly) as [object object]

Comment: data.name is an object, the string representation of an object is `[object object]`. You probably should instead output a property containing a string value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you get a problem with serialisation of an object what you received from your api. Make sure the data.name is really a string and accessible.Below a working example with another example api to show that your code will work.

```js
let dataBtn;
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  return await response.json();

}
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btnGet");
const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const data = await fetchData();
  console.log(data);
  container.appendChild(newDiv).innerHTML = data.title;
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button id="btnGet">GET</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to write code like this: data[0]

Comment: Please be sure to include crucial information in your answer such as: what the problem is, what the solution is, why that solution works, and an example if applicable. Do not just write an answer without context